# How to use *.pfx certificate for Amazon ELB SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, pfx

I have cert.pfx file, I need to install to be used in Amazon Elastic Load Balancer.
How can I do it?

Comment: Rather sounds like a question that your favourite search enginge will answer (or aws docs/customer support)

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Because it's QA style question, and I spent over two days on getting a clear and working answer which is below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Extract private key without password. First command will request `pfx` password and prompt for a password for `key.pem`; **a password for `key.pem` must be provided**. Second command asks for `key.pem` password provided for 1st command.

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key`

2. Extract certificate:

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem`

3. Extract certificate chain:

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nodes -nokeys -out chain.pem`

4. Certificate chain contains several items. You may need to remove item that refers to your certificate, it's on top and it's not needed. Give a try with/without removing top item.
   After that the other items should be placed in reverse order.
5. server.key is private key in ELB, cert.pem is certificate in ELB, output #4 is certificate chain.

Good luck!

Comment: Really make sure you provide a password for key.pem - it doesn't complain if you don't so you end up with a broken file.

Comment: Sometimes the cert does not contain the intermediate CA certs, and the chain.pem is empty in that case. And AWS does not accept such thing. I found a solution via this article: https://chadstechnoworks.com/wptech/os/how_to_extract_root_and_intermediate_certificates_from_client_certificate.html

Answer (score 3):

you can easily convert the format of the certificate using the OpenSSL suite.

The process is very easy and a good guide is here: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/16.cfm.

About the different steps (taken from the link I reported above):

```
# Export the private key file from the pfx file
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem

# Export the certificate file from the pfx file
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem

# This removes the passphrase from the private key so Apache won't
# prompt you for your passphase when it starts
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key
```

Now, if you have a linux distro, it is straight forward to install openSSL (yum install openssl on an rpm based distro).

If you don't have a linux distro installed, then the quickest would be to go for a live distribution (I personally love fedora https://getfedora.org/)

I hope this helps

Comment: What cad do a man to get some more karma on SO? Even not read the question at all, which is specific to Amazon ELB SSL.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to help. Didn't see that the previous response was from you.

My advice is to close and accept your response so that your (incomplete question) won't pop-up again in the list

Have a good day

Comment: I would happily mark mine as answer if SO allow me to do it. Actually I can't do it for 48h since question posting, even if it's Q/A style. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

First go to Certificate Manager and import your certificate [cert, key, chain], then create AWS LB with existing certificate.

Comment: He doesn't have a cert, key, and chain.  He has a single file, *.pfx.  He is mostly complaining (legitimately) that AWS doesn't allow you to import a pfx file like seemingly every other place allows you to do.